# Aligning multiple rows to fit on one line in Excel using a macro

Tags: excel, vba

I have some excel data that comes from a lab in a strange format and am trying to figure out how to put all of the patient data on the same line. An example is below, with a single entry highlighted in red so you can see that the whole thing spans 3 lines:

[image]

I think a macro would work well for something like this but recording macros is the extent of my knowledge. I do not really know how to write VBA. The goal is to get all patient information on the same row so that they can be filtered (example below):

[image]

What I have done to figure this out on my own: I began recording a macro and manually changing things (for the recording) when I realized that the references might change depending on the heading of the worksheet, which changes.  I *could* do a relative reference macro but then pointing the cursor to the right spot for each patient over and over is almost as much work as doing it by hand. It seemed like there should be a way to say "everything contained in three lines is one 'entry', so put on one line, starting here and ending there" or something?

Comment: VBA could help here for sure.  Quick question - is the "DOB" column always going to look like that (i.e. date, then next cell is age, then date, then next cell age, etc. or will there possibly be a gap in there somewhere?)

Comment: @user3578951 and chancea: I updated the images to exactly reflect what is going on in the worksheet. There are a few weird ones which made me think it was a bit random but almost all of the entries look just like what I have now posted. Thanks for checking

Comment: So, is it safe to say that: The row with a person's name will have, in column E, info one row above, and one row below, that need to be combined?  Does that make sense? It looks like for each entry, the row with a name in it will need Address combined (from one row above, and one below), the DOB matched with Age, and the phone number up one row.

Comment: Could you clarify if this data comes thru as XLS, XLSX, CSV, or some other format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How's this:

```
Sub text()
Dim lastRow As Integer, ageCol As Integer, addressCol As Integer, i As Integer, endRow As Integer
Dim startRow As Integer, phoneCol As Integer

lastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
ageCol = Rows(1).Find(what:="DOB_Age").Column
addressCol = Rows(1).Find(what:="Address").Column
phoneCol = Rows(1).Find(what:="Phone").Column

'Starting off, go to first name in the list.
startRow = Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Row
endRow = Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For i = startRow To endRow
    Cells(i, 1).Select
    If Cells(i, 1).Value <> "" Then
        Cells(i, ageCol).Value = Cells(i, ageCol).Value & " " & Cells(i, ageCol).Offset(1, 0).Value
        Cells(i, addressCol).Value = Cells(i, addressCol).Offset(-1, 0).Value & ", " & Cells(i, addressCol).Value & ", " & Cells(i, addressCol).Offset(1, 0).Value
        Cells(i, phoneCol).Value = Cells(i, phoneCol).Offset(1, 0).Value
        ' Now, let's clear the data we copied over.
        Cells(i, ageCol).Offset(1, 0).Value = ""
        Cells(i, addressCol).Offset(-1, 0).Value = ""
        Cells(i, addressCol).Offset(1, 0).Value = ""
        Cells(i, phoneCol).Offset(1, 0).Value = ""
    End If
Next i

'Now, let's delete all the empty rows
For i = 1 To endRow
    If i > endRow Then Exit For
    If IsEmpty(Cells(i, 1)) Then
        Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Delete
        i = i - 1
        endRow = Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Note: This assumes that your data will always look like your question - the row with a name on it has ONE row above and ONE row below that need to be moved to the name's row.  Please let me know what works/what doesn't work and needs tweaking.  Good luck!

Comment: This worked perfectly for me! I really did want a VBA solution because we get a lot of these files in. My real file is slightly different (just more columns) than the sample I gave but I am looking forward to combing through your code and tweaking it to fit my real data. Thank you!

Comment: Glad to hear it - let me know if there's a tweak you need but can't figure out, or have any questions about the above.

Answer (score 0):

#### Multiple Formula (Non-VBA) Solution:

This option would be to get the values to appear in another sheet using formulas and autofilling down.

Note: this option assumes that *all* your data is as shown in the images, currently I do not account for any exceptions (which can be added)

Here are the formulas (using "Sheet1" as the reference sheet, change that to whatever your sheet name is):

(Horizontal view, ..have fun scrolling..)

```
    A                                 B                                 C                                 D                                                                                         E                                                                                                                  F
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1|  Id                                Patient_Name                      Sex                               DOB_Age                                                                                   Address                                                                                                           Phone
2|  =INDIRECT("Sheet1!A"&(ROW()-1)*3) =INDIRECT("Sheet1!B"&(ROW()-1)*3) =INDIRECT("Sheet1!C"&(ROW()-1)*3) =TEXT(INDIRECT("Sheet1!D"&(ROW()-1)*3),"m/d/yyy")&", "&INDIRECT("Sheet1!D"&(ROW()-1)*3+1) =INDIRECT("Sheet1!E"&(ROW()-1)*3-1)&", "&INDIRECT("Sheet1!E"&(ROW()-1)*3)&", "&INDIRECT("Sheet1!E"&(ROW()-1)*3+1) =INDIRECT("Sheet1!F"&(ROW()-1)*3+1)
3| ..Autofill down..
```

(Vertical view)

```
Id                                
=INDIRECT("Sheet1!A"&(ROW()-1)*3)   
Patient_Name
=INDIRECT("Sheet1!B"&(ROW()-1)*3)
Sex 
=INDIRECT("Sheet1!C"&(ROW()-1)*3)
DOB_Age 
=TEXT(INDIRECT("Sheet1!D"&(ROW()-1)*3),"m/d/yyy")&", "&INDIRECT("Sheet1!D"&(ROW()-1)*3+1)
Address 
=INDIRECT("Sheet1!E"&(ROW()-1)*3-1)&", "&INDIRECT("Sheet1!E"&(ROW()-1)*3)&", "&INDIRECT("Sheet1!E"&(ROW()-1)*3+1)
Phone
=INDIRECT("Sheet1!F"&(ROW()-1)*3+1)
```

Now since these are formulas and not vba, the data will automatically change if the source changes.  So if you want to only keep the values you can `copy -> paste special -> values` on a new sheet to keep only the values

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Parse_Data()
    Dim rngTarget As Range, x As Long

    Set rngTarget = Worksheets("Target").Range("A2")

    For x = 2 To Range("E1").Offset(Rows.Count - 1).End(xlUp).Row
        Select Case x Mod 3
            Case 2
                rngTarget.Offset(, 5).Value = Range("A1").Offset(x - 1, 4).Value
            Case 0
                rngTarget.Offset(, 0).Value = Range("A1").Offset(x - 1, 0).Value
                rngTarget.Offset(, 1).Value = Range("A1").Offset(x - 1, 1).Value
                rngTarget.Offset(, 2).Value = Range("A1").Offset(x - 1, 2).Value
                rngTarget.Offset(, 3).Value = Range("A1").Offset(x - 1, 3).Value
                rngTarget.Offset(, 6).Value = Range("A1").Offset(x - 1, 4).Value
            Case 1
                rngTarget.Offset(, 4).Value = Range("A1").Offset(x - 1, 3).Value
                rngTarget.Offset(, 7).Value = Range("A1").Offset(x - 1, 4).Value
                rngTarget.Offset(, 8).Value = Range("A1").Offset(x - 1, 5).Value
                Set rngTarget = rngTarget.Offset(1)
        End Select
    Next x
End Sub
```